# Refresh ComboBox After Adding New Values via a Separate Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the name of client (Create.cshtml).

if a client didn't existe in the Droplist, I'd like to allow the user to do it in a separate Form, but the user have to choose it after from the DropList in the Create.cshtml, without loosing any other information he enter in the Create.cshtml.

Can I refresh only the Dropdownlist ?

This is the code for the ClientName

```
<label>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)</label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientNameList, new SelectList(Model.ClientName, "idClient", "Client"), new { style = "width:100px;height:30px;font-size:13px" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientName)
```

Thanks

Comment: Create a popup form for a new client and use AJAX to post to a controller method that returns the new clients ID and Name, then on success add the new client to the dropdown list

Comment: You can also have the options you want to refresh in a partial view and have some AJAX form. Post this form and update only the partial. This will let you keep all other information except the target div of your ajax form